# Bootstrap datetimepicker does not show when clicked on button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sharepoint, onclick, datetimepicker

I have a bootstrap datetimepicker, and I have this piece of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.*js"></script>
<link href="../../_layouts/16/STYLES/XXX/css/bootstrap/bootstrap3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <asp:Label ID="LabelValidoDe" runat="server" Text="Válido de:"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListValidoDe" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepickervalidode'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepickervalidode').datetimepicker();
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

When I go to the calendar Icon and I clicked on it, it doesn't show anything and I don't know why. It changes my mouse icon to a hand, instead of an arrow, but it doesn't show anything.

Can anyone helps me? Thanks a lot!

**EDIT:**

The new code, after DatGeoudon answer:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <asp:Label ID="LabelValidoDe" runat="server" Text="Válido de:"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListValidoDe" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date'>
                <input id='datetimepickervalidode' type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepickervalidode').datetimepicker();
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: have you checked your  js framework load order? Also check if console throws any error.

Answer (score 0):

Your id `#datetimepickervalidode` is a div's id but datetimepicker() needs an input.

Comment: I change it, but it still does the same, I post an edit, wait, please.

Comment: You have an `*` into the ui's source.